# Receive audio file via socket

Tags: c++, c, sockets, audio, recv

I am trying to receive a file (audio, .CAF) from a socket in C (C++ solution ok as well).  I have the socket communication working, having tested it with strings.  My problem is I don't know what to supply to the 2nd arg in recv(socket, buffer, buffer_size, 0). What type should I make "buffer"?  I basically want to receive an audio file, and will then play it.  But don't know how to receive the audio file itself.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Robin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, you'll have the audio encoded in some format. For simplicity, let's assume it's Wave format.

One way of doing things would be to encapsulate chunks of the audio (Say, 50 ms chunks) for sending over the network.

However, you can't blindly send data over the network and expect it to work. On your computer, data may be organized one way (little or big endian), and it could be organized in the opposite way on the other computer.

In that case, the client will get data that he interprets as being completely different than what you intended. So, you'll need to properly serialize it somehow.

Once you properly serialize the data though (or not, if both computers use the same endianess!), you can just send() it and rcev() it, then just pass it off to a decoder to deal with.

I'd love to offer more information, but that's about the extent of my knowledge on the subject. It really depends on what exactly you're doing, so it's hard to give any more information without some more specifics as to what you're doing (with regards to audio format, for one).

Some more information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Edit: As pointed out in the comments of this answer, you should probably not worry about serialization at all if you're using a standard format. Just pass it over the network in chunks that are usable by your decoder (Send a frame at a time, for example) then decode those individual frames (or possibly multiple frames) on the client side.

Comment: I believe the serialization/endianness issues should be taken care of by the file format itself unless it's not designed to be a cross-platform file format.

Comment: So it would be safe to assume that if I transmitted some wave frames over my network, I can reasonably expect it to come out the right way on the other end? I've never really dealt with this issue before, since I've only done basic networking.

Comment: You can expect the endianness to stay the same as what was specified in the file format. This allows you to transfer the file using any method from platforms that differ in endianness. The endianness of the file format may be different than the target platform's endianness, but the decoder should take care of that.

Answer (score 2):

`buffer` is going to be a pointer to an array you've allocated to store the data the comes across the wire.

It depends on the socket library you're using, but usually it expects `void*` (which is just a generic pointer type).

You might do something like this:

```
uint8[1000] myBuffer;
recv(sock,myBuffer,1000,0);
```

It gets tricky because this only gives you enough room for 8,000bytes, which might not be enough to hold your audio file, so you'll have to handle multiple recv() calls until you get the entire audio file.